# Automatic expansion of cluster using puppet

Tags: puppet

We are using puppet to configure our product for virtual images. We are using /etc/hosts to list the nodes in our cluster like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
x.x.x.x node-1
y.y.y.y node-2
z.z.z.z node-3
x.x.x.x this_node_ip
```

This file is the same on all nodes except for the this_node_ip that is unique for all nodes( needed by application that has to have common configuration)

Our problem comes with expansion where we want /etc/hosts to be distributed with new nodes on all machines automatically when a new node starts up and connects to puppet master.

Our thought was to have a puppet template for /etc/hosts that keeps it synced with a fact for this_node_ip but how do we add new nodes in to the template?

Is there someway to list all agents connected to master in a fact? 
So that we could populate our /etc/hosts with a for each loop based on connected agents? 
Template would in that case be something like:

```
<% @list_of_nodes.split(',').each |ip, hostname| %>
<%= ip %> <%= hostname%>
<% end -%>
<%= ipadress_eth0 %> this_node_ip
```

Currently our only idea on way forward is to have new nodes scp a new template to puppetmaster node with all nodes hardcoded to update /etc/hosts file of old nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, please don't ;-)

Each of your machines can dynamically export its own node entry.

```
@@host { $fqdn: ip => $ipaddress, tag => 'my-tag-foobar' }
```

...and collect the exports from all peers

```
Host<<| tag == 'my-tag-foobar' |>>
```

Do set up PuppetDB on your master to allow this to work.

You should not manage `/etc/hosts` as a complete file, because you lose the flexibility that Puppet's `host` resource offers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is most likely the correct way of doing it. However, it seems that this solution will be shot down due to the db requirement. Been trying to test it but having a lot of trouble getting the connection between puppet and puppetdb to work, when I try to use default of puppetdb I get:  Could not retrieve facts for node-2: Failed to find facts from PuppetDB at puppetdb:8081: Server hostname 'puppetdb' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster, DNS:puppetmaster

Comment: @Sam Did you set it up using the `puppetlabs-puppetdb` module? Make sure to pass the correct `fqdn` in as a parameter. It should match your `CN` ("puppetmaster"?).